# Azure data factory "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" on sink "contact" table only

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

Getting below error on sink contact table using dataflow(tried both Dataverse and D365 connector), it is working on account table and other custom tables also.

> Operation on target Data flow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'contact': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0","Details":"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.store.dynamics.DynamicsWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$36.apply(DynamicsStore.scala:257)\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.store.dynamics.DynamicsWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$36.apply(DynamicsStore.scala:257)\n\tat scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)\n\tat scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)\n\tat scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)\n\tat scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.store.dynamics.DynamicsWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(DynamicsStore.scala:257)\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.store.dynamics.DynamicsWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(DynamicsStore.scala:251)\n\tat scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow"}

Kindly Help
[image: error screenshot on sink]

Comment: without any much idea could you look at this [q&a] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/785387/job-failed-due-to-reason-at-sink-39sinkx39-javalan.html)
maybe it will give you some idea.

Comment: Seems like no response from MSFT on the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the question in the Q&A. The issue was resolved internally by Microsoft. After a few weeks of waiting, they rolled out a release that solved the issue. Since then, our pipelines haven't failed because of that. I think your best chance is to open a support ticket from Azure Portal, or posting a new question in the Q&A section, linking to my question and see if they do something else for you.